# how to save photo and upload it in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have uploaded an image to a content  page and finally i want to save it on that page only what i do ? i can do either by binding or by dynamically created folder please do tell me one of the procedure.

```
     var profile = new Image { };

     // profile.Source = im;
       profile.Source = "profile.png";
        profile.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
        profile.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;

        profile.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "LabelText");
        var profiletap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

        profiletap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
        {
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (file == null)
                return;
            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
            var filepath = file.Path;

            im = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();

                //file.Dispose();
                return stream;


            });



         profile.Source = im;
```

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27122/saving-images-using-xamarin-forums. After saving you can retrieve that image on page load everytime you visit the page.

Comment: okk please give me all the code i am begginner and fresher ..in face how to save and retrive in xamarin

Comment: please show me the code i need it my boss is seated on my head

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin.forms how to hold my image on same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722348/xamarin-forms-how-to-hold-my-image-on-same-page)